# ViewPager event destroyItem very slow

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a test on ViewPager about the time between `onPageSelected` and `destroyItem` and I have found that it's very slow. It took an average 200-700 miliseconds to trigger the `destroyItem` event after page is selected, this is my code:

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
private ViewPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ViewPagerChangeListener mChangeListener;
private long time;

int[] resources = {
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
        R.mipmap.ic_launcher
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get the ViewFlipper
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mChangeListener = new ViewPagerChangeListener();
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(mChangeListener);
    mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1000;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == (ImageView)object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        Log.d("Time", "paging being instantiate:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
        ImageView view = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        int p = position;
        if(p > 5)
            p = 5;
        view.setImageResource(resources[p]);

        container.addView(view, 0);
        Log.d("Time", "paging after instantiated:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        Log.d("Time", "paging being destroy:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
        container.removeView((ImageView)object);
        Log.d("Time", "paging after destroyed:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
    }
}

class ViewPagerChangeListener implements android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
}
```

Here is the test result when I request the right page (When requesting the left page, the `instantiateItem` event will be called before the `destroyItem` event)

```
paging being destroy:639
paging after destroyed:640
paging being instantiate:640
paging after instantiated:641
```

The question is, are there any ways to force the pager adapter call event to destroy faster than normal?

Comment: Why do you need a view pager with 1000 items?

Comment: Cause I don't now how many items, I only get the next item after had one and so on...I think the size of adapter is not important, at the same time, there are only 3 items, right?

Comment: Yes, by default there will be only 3 items on adapter. Screen 1 will get destroyed only when you navigate right to screen 3. Calculating time to destroy screen1 when you are in screen3 doesn't make any sense to me. Also according to your data it is taking only 1 milli second to execute ' container.removeView'. Are you facing any performance issue ? like view pager is taking long to navigate between pages?

Comment: I mean the time between two events `pageselected` and `destroyitem`. It's take too long